# Ubuntu 18.04 - A script to shut down a PC in an event

Tags: nvidia, scripts, shutdown, conky

With support from here or on other forums, I have managed to launch the nVidia Render Farm Multi GPU for network computing in Octane Render Slave Daemon.

Now I am trying to find a way - standalone script or nested in Conky setting, which will allow to shut down PC at certain event?

I need more precisely:
When monitoring nvidia-settings = GPU Utilization will be less than 10% for eg 300sec, then shut down the computer.

So far I have this script from another user to shut down my PC.
But I need to extend it by another time-out condition to avoid turning off the PC as soon as the value falls below 10%. Since there are some load variations in the calculation (for example, from one frame of the animation to the next).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
GPU=$(execi 60 nvidia-settings -query [gpu:0]/GPUCoreTemp -t)
if [[ ${GPU} -le 10 ]]; then
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.PowerOff boolean:false
fi
```

Comment: you really do not want to be using conky for this (or at all on a render farm that might need all the overhead it can get. If you want to monitor your gpus, use nvidia-smi : https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface which is made for that purpose) conky is terribly optimised code and a desktop widget should never be the thing tasked with shutting down the system. what you're looking for is `cron`/`crontab`

Comment: I designed the conky because it is already running on the mentioned PC and I have a graphical display (bar) for monitoring the load of all GPUs over it.
Of course I am willing to explore another solution. Especially when it is user friendly and meets the requirements of the function.
nVidia-smi I have, but unfortunately does not return the GPU Utilization value. I found out that perhaps nVidia in navidia-smi refused to support some cards. On other cards, the functions are limited. For example, for me, nvidia-smi is able to detect GPU temperature and frequency

Comment: nvidia-smi is made to return the gpu utilisation value, you may not have seen it in the long list of values. I'll grant you it's not as user-firendly but it's certainly better optimised, if you script something to pick up certain values from nvidia-smi you can make yourself a gui that is nicely optimised , this guy has : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/288611/228658 (another similar solution in the same thread : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342865/228658 actually https://github.com/Syllo/nvtop) , you can use his script if you want. but stick with conky if you don't feel like it.

Comment: nvidia-smi, on the other hand, is very clear as a table. I found the Utilization easily in the overview, but the output only answers "N/A". I conclude that for my current build of cards (nVidia GTX 780 Ti) is not able to detect the value.
Conversely, nvidia-settings returns this value without any trouble.

Comment: curious indeed. but nevermind all this. did you look into `crontab`?

Answer (score 1):

Good day,
I finally came up with a solution and forgot to list it here for other users.
1) the function nvidia-smi utilization.gpu is not supported for GPU 780 Ti, it was necessary to modify the script asking for the value fan.speed
2) with the upgrade to a higher range of GPUs, all nvidia-smi features are supported, including utilization.gpu

Over fan.speed - nVidia GPU series lower than 8

```
    #!/bin/bash
echo $(date +"%T") >> $HOME/Octane/GPU-off.log
echo "1) FIRST VERIFICATION"
GPU1=$(exec nvidia-smi --format=csv,noheader,nounits --id=0 --query-gpu=fan.speed)
echo $GPU1
if [[ ${GPU1} -le 40 ]]; then
    sleep 15m
    echo $(date +"%T") >> $HOME/Octane/GPU-off.log
    echo "2) SECOND VERIFICATION"
    GPU2=$(exec nvidia-smi --format=csv,noheader,nounits --id=0 --query-gpu=fan.speed)
    echo $GPU2
    if [[ ${GPU2} -le 40 ]]; then
        sleep 15m
        echo $(date +"%T") >> $HOME/Octane/GPU-off.log
        echo "3) SHUTDOWN"
        GPU3=$(exec nvidia-smi --format=csv,noheader,nounits --id=0 --query-gpu=fan.speed)
        echo $GPU3
        if [[ ${GPU3} -le 40 ]]; then
            echo $(date +"%T") >> $HOME/Octane/GPU-off.log
            sudo poweroff
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Over utiluzation.gpu

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(date +"%T") >> $HOME/Octane/GPU-off.log
echo "1) FIRST VERIFICATION"
GPU1=$(exec nvidia-smi --format=csv,noheader,nounits --id=0 --query-gpu=utilization.gpu)
echo $GPU1
if [[ ${GPU1} -le 10 ]]; then
    sleep 15m
    echo $(date +"%T") >> $HOME/Octane/GPU-off.log
    echo "2) SECOND VERIFICATION"
    GPU2=$(exec nvidia-smi --format=csv,noheader,nounits --id=0 --query-gpu=utilization.gpu)
    echo $GPU2
    if [[ ${GPU2} -le 10 ]]; then
        sleep 15m
        echo $(date +"%T") >> $HOME/Octane/GPU-off.log
        echo "3) SHUTDOWN"
        GPU3=$(exec nvidia-smi --format=csv,noheader,nounits --id=0 --query-gpu=utilization.gpu)
        echo $GPU3
        if [[ ${GPU3} -le 10 ]]; then
            echo $(date +"%T") >> $HOME/Octane/GPU-off.log
            sudo poweroff
        fi
    fi
fi
```